# Passing parameters via email

Tags: c#, email, mailmessage

Many applications use emails for accounts verification and other different purposes.You can see that those emails contain Buttons that redirect you to a certain page with a url parameters(ex:http://users/1234....).

How can I do the same functionality if I am constructing the email programmatically using `MailMessage` utility.

Comment: Are you asking how to put a URL in an email?

Comment: @SLaks the whole process, and redirect via a button

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking how query strings work? The buttons are just links with background colors.

Comment: @SLaks yes, but there is a process behind it,password reset for example.There is session like behind it or hidden fields inside the email

Comment: Wrong.  There is just a querystring parameter that gets looked up in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly the Confirmation you talking about is a process. So, for example,

- create a user with a guid and a ConfirmationDate in a database table.
- sent a mail with a link and the guid
- if the user clicks the link you set the ConfirmationDate
- if the user has a ConfirmationDate (not null) the user has confirmed

Answer (score 0):

Set mail.IsBodyHtml to true and use HTML.